# Обновление TForm (Lazarus)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

У меня есть две формы. У каждой формы есть кнопка перехода на другую форму.

Как сделать так,чтобы при переходе на другую форму последняя обнуляла все свои переменные и объекты на ней,проще говоря обновлялась. Я написал такой код.

```
procedure TForm1.Panel8Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form1.Hide;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);      
  Form2.Show;
end;
```

По идее при нажатии на кнопку, Form2 должна создаваться заново,но почему то переменные на ней, если они были изменены до этого,сохраняют свои значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаляйте существующий объект `Form2` перед созданием нового.

```
Form2.Free;
Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
```

Э-э-э... Покажите, пожалуйста, пример "переменной на ней".

Comment: Я имел в виду переменные,которые изменяются в юните привязанном к этой форме,извините за неточность.

Comment: @JohnS - То есть - глобальные переменные? Они не будут принимать первоначальные значения при создании нового экземпляра формы.

Comment: @JohnS - Сделайте их членами класса TForm2 и проблема решится.

Comment: @JohnS - или присваивайте им первоначальные значения в конструкторе TForm2.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы,но не могли бы вы подробнее объяснить как сделать переменные членами класса. Есть строка implementation и наверное { TForm2 } означает класс,тогда мне нужно создать var после этой строки с моими переменными?

Comment: В части interface юнита Form2.pas есть такие слова: `TForm2 = class(TForm) ... end;`. Все что на месте "..." - члены класса TForm2. Перенесите Ваши переменные в секцию `private`.